# Problem accessing relationship objects in an NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

My managed object has a relationship called `items`. My subclass has a method called `itemCount`. Unfortunatly my attempts to get the object count in the *items* relationship always returns 0. Here's the relevant code:

```
@interface List : NSManagedObject {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* items;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber * itemCount;

@end

@implementation List

@dynamic items;

- (NSNumber *)itemCount 
{
    NSNumber * tmpValue;

    NSSet *items = self.items;
    if (items = nil) {
        return 0;
    }
    tmpValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[items count]];

    return tmpValue;
}

@end
```

When I walk through the itemCount method it appears to work just fine, but the `self.items` counts always return zero objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're assigning `nil` to `items` in your `if` statement. You want `if (items == nil)` (or `if (!items)`). Always use the debugger to step through your code to test your logic when something odd is happening.

Second of all, you can get the count with the keypath, `@"@count.items"` without the need for your `-itemCount` method. You could also do `self.items.count` (because `count` is a property of the `items` set as `items` is a property of `self`, which is equivalent to `[[self items] count]`).

Comment: Thanks! I figured it'd be something trivial.